# how to call action after every 2 minute in reactjs with await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I am using async await for calling API in react, My question is how can I call get service in every 2 minutes, because in my case promise is not resolving its taking time and showing pending state, so I am thinking to call get service in every 2 minutes if promise is not resolved. Can someone guide me how can I do this using await.

here is my code what I have done.

```
export function fetchUser(id) {
  return async dispatch => {
    let userUrl = FETCH_USER_URL + id;
    let response1 = await get(userUrl); // I want to call this again if response not getting within a 2 minutes

    if (response1.status === 200) {

       let processUrl = FETCH_PROCESS_USER_URL;
       let response2 = await get(processUrl);
    if (response2.status === 200) {
       console.log("fetch process user success");
    } else {
       console.log("fetch process user failed");
    }
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      console.log("failed");
    }
  };
}
```

any help will appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 minutes is a long time for a request to be pending. Are you sure there isn't something else that has gone wrong?

Comment: no from backend they are holding request till 3 minutes.this is worst case scenario for waiting to 3 minutes but I still want to cover it, because of that I am thinking to call service in ever 2 or 1 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(fetchUser(id), 120000);

let response = await get(url);

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

#### Edit because of comment:

```js
export function fetchUser(id) {
  return async dispatch => {
    let url = FETCH_USER_URL + id;
    const timeout = setTimeout(fetchUser(id), 120000); // start 2 min timer that will call the function again in 2 min

    let response = await get(url); // if response not getting within a 2 minutes call again

    clearTimeout(timeout); //remove it if you get a response before 2min


    if (response.status === 200) {

       let url2 = FETCH_PROCESS_USER_URL;
       let response2 = await get(url);
    if (response2.status === 200) {
       console.log("fetch process user success");
    } else {
       console.log("fetch process user failed");
    }
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      console.log("failed");
    }
  };
}
,,,
```

Comment: I have updated the code,because what you have answered i am unable to understand as I am new to reactjs, can you just see the my updated code that is what i am actually doing.

Comment: fetchUser() I am calling this action into my two different container. by exporting it but in your answer you have used differently because of that i am unable to understand. @linkinmedo

Comment: check the edit, I think your code can be much cleaner but I don't know what exactly are you doing so I didn't change any thing but the variable names because it's not a good practice to use the same name.

Comment: ok will change the variable name to understand more clearly. Thanks for reply

Comment: thank you for giving your valuable time. @linkinmedo

Comment: @Nammu anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this approach.

```js
const NUM_RETRIES = 3;

test();

async function getData() {
  let arr = new Array(NUM_RETRIES).map(() => null);
  arr.forEach(() => {
    try {
      await get('url');
    } catch (err) {}
  });
}
```